# jQuery validate single input in similar forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have two forms on a page that are identical, but I'm trying to validate the one field (which is email in this case), but I can't seem to get it to just validate the one input field as it just shows the error for both forms.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="general-form">
  <div class="email-error" style="display:none;">
    <p>You need valid email</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="form-row">
      <input id="from-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-row">
      <button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="general-form">
  <div class="email-error" style="display:none;">
    <p>You need valid email</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="form-row">
      <input id="from-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-row">
      <button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".submit-btn").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var valid_email = $this.find("#from-email").val();
  if (/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(valid_email)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    $this.parents().find(".email-error").show();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Overall, I can get it to pass through the validation, but the error message shows for **both** forms and I'm not sure how to get it so it only shows the error message for that particular form. I'm guessing that I'm pushing too far up the chain and it's testing for both of the forms, but I can't remember which one to target specifically if that makes any sense.

Comment: IDs should be unique. Having two inputs with the id `from-email` is not valid

Comment: Do these forms have `<form>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doubled the id `from-email` that’s why. In your JS you are checking all fields with the id `from-email` in this case both of the inputs are checked because both the id.

If one of them is wrong you are searching for the `email-error` in all of your parents which will go up to the body and then find all off the error wrappers.  `$this.parents(“.general-form“)` will do the deal and only go up to the wrapper of the input and error in your case.

Always make sure your id’s are unique.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I might need to add an iterator when the form gets generated. But in the case of adding the specific class name to the parents, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add required> attribute and add this js

```
$("#formid").validate();
```